# IIS 10 when I try to rename a website I get the website already exists

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to rename a website in IIS and I get the message:

> a site with this name already exists.

It might have something to do with me installing IIS on my new  computer but the last website with the name I wanted to rename must be stuck somewhere?

Thanks for any help and/or advice.

Comment: Open IIS configuration file and then edit that instead. You can easily search if another site uses the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to change the casing of a site name. IIS complained that the new name already existed. This seems to be a bug in IIS. I had to rename the site to an new (dummy) value and then change it back to the old name with correct casing.

Answer (score 0):

This error means a site already exists in IIS which has the same name as the value chosen.
IIS site names must be unique. While deploying application, a unique site name must be used.